# Allure generates empty reports page on local machine

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, testng, allure

As the title says I cannot force `Allure 2` to generate reports for me on local machine. 
I've tried a lot of things from Google but nothing helped. I use Kotlin+Selenide+TestNG to write tests, if it helps somehow :) 
I'm a little bit confused with `Allure` because it has version for `testNG` and version for `Gradle` - which one should be used? Both? 
Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
group 'RegisteredUserFlow'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.2-2"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "ru.d10xa:gradle-allure-plugin:0.5.5"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ru.d10xa.allure'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

allure {
    aspectjweaver = true
    testNG = true
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    agent
}

dependencies {
    agent "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-2"
    testCompile "com.codeborne:selenide:4.4.3"
    testCompile "org.testng:testng:6.10"
    testCompile "io.qameta.allure:allure-testng:2.0-BETA6"
    testCompile "io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:1.6.2"
}

test.doFirst {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}"
}

test {
    useTestNG(){
        suites 'src/test/kotlin/testng.xml'
    }
    systemProperty 'allure.results.directory', 'build/allure-results'
    systemProperty 'allure.link.issue.pattern', 'https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-docs/issues/{}'
    systemProperty 'allure.link.tms.pattern', 'https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-docs/issues/{}'
}

tasks.withType(Test)*.finalizedBy allureReport
```

Commands I used were: `allure serve build/allure-results` and `gradlew clean test allureReport`

Also, do I need Java plugin?

Appreciate any help! 
Thanks!

P.S. Here's the error I get in console after `gradlew clean test allureReport` command:

```
Execution failed for task ':allureReport'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':allureReport'.
   > Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12.
     Required by:
         project : > ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-bundle:1.4.24.RC3 > org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12
         project : > ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-bundle:1.4.24.RC3 > ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-report-data:1.4.24.RC3 > ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-report-plugin-api:1.4.24.RC3 > ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-model:1.4.24.RC3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ru.d10xa:gradle-allure-plugin:0.5.5` is not support Allure 2. We are working on brand new Allure Gradle plugin that available here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-gradle

At the moment you can use allure-commandline to generate the report at local machine and Allure Jenkins/Teamcity plugin to generate the report on CI.

#### Update

New Allure Gradle plugin that supports Allure 2 is available now. See the docs https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_gradle_3 for more details.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your response.